# Adding diagonal lines through several numbers in table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I was wondering how I should reproduce this image in LaTeX, is there a package that can help me do these diagonal lines in an array environment or is the only viable solution TikZ?

### Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! do you mean reproducing the black numbers only?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!. Perhaps this post could help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577350/how-to-draw-an-arrow-with-a-label-head-inside-a-tabular.